# Forcing an application pool to run in 32 bit mode kills the application pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, 32bit-64bit, application-pool

So I have an asp.net web site which was built using the "Any CPU" setting. The website uses excel through COM. I have excel 2007 installed on SBS 2011 (x64).

Excel 2007 is 32-bit so I had to change the "Enable 32 bit applications" (in the application pool) setting to true. However as soon as I do this the Application Pool stops (not immediately but as soon as I try to request a page).

I have re-compiled the site in "x86" mode, but to no avail.

(Note that the IIS version I'm using is 7.5)

Any insight on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is often a problem with the 64 bit rpcproxy.dll which is loaded by iis by default even when "enable 32 bit applications" is set to true.

Having problems with this myself.

Here's the link

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/04/07/how-to-run-a-32bit-web-application-on-sbs-2008.aspx

Wing